Why is the unionset axiom framed in the way it is?
I'm currently simulataneously learning set theory from "Notes on set theory" by Yiannis Moschovakis, "Set Theory" by Thomas Jech and "Analysis" by Terence Tao. In two of these textbooks (Jech and Moschovakis), I find the process of formulating the unionset axiom a bit peculiar. The method is as follows.
You first define the union of a single set. Assuming that there exists a set $A$, this axiom posits that there exists a set $B$ such that $x\in B\iff \exists z(z\in A\land x\in z)$. Here, $\cup A = B$. Then, the definition $A\cup B := \cup\{A,B\}$ is made where $A\cup B$ has the traditional notion that $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A\lor x\in B$.
While I do understand this line of reasoning, I wonder why such an unnecessarily lengthy approach is taken. Instead, like Tao has done, why don't the other textbooks simply define that $A\cup B := \{x|x\in A\lor x\in B\}$? What's the catch? Why go through the seemingly unnecessary process of defining the union of a single set, $\cup A$?

What you call the union of $A$, I might actually call "the union of all elements of $A$".
The benefit of doing it this way is that you get a notion of a union of infinitely many sets. If you define union as a binary operation first, then you can prove it is associative, and then be able to take arbitrarily (but finitely) long union chains like
$$
A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots\cup A_n
$$
but you will not be able to use this to take the union of, say, all the sets of real sequences that are zero past a given point
$$
A_k = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots)\in \Bbb R^n\mid i>k\implies x_i =0\}
$$
to construct the set of eventually-zero sequences. And while the infinite union of all these $A_k$ is possible to construct in other ways, ultimately, infinite unions are just very, very useful. So this more general notion of union needs to be defined. And once you have established that it needs to be defined, definining the binary union in terms of the more general union may be the most ergonomic way of going about it, rather than defining it to be its own thing.
Of course, I won't pretend like this way of going about it is absolutely the best way, especially in a teaching setting. Maybe introducing the binary union first is a good idea. Then when the need for an infinite union presents itself, point out what the issue is, and then you can define the more general notion. I haven't read Tao's book, but I suspect that's how he will go about it. I can't imagine he will use infinite unions without properly defining them.

I think this is missing the set theory reasons for why we define it like this. In particular existence of set ${x : x\in A \lor x\in B}$

@Jakobian The axiom of union is part of the ZF axioms. It prescribes the existence of all the sets we need (possibly, depending on your verson, in conjunction with specification). I didn't think that that was really necessary to go into. Of course, this axiom is usually phrased more in line with the general notion of union, precisely to allow for the more general (and potentially infinite) unions one might need.

@Jakobian: I read the post in a different way than you did. The OP seemed content with the definition of $A \cup B$, but seemed unable to percieve $\cup A$ as a more general kind of union, namely the union of an arbitary set of sets.

Alright, I misunderstood the OP. They were asking about reasons for why the axiom of union is as it is, and I was thinking of this from standpoint that we already agreed upon axioms of set theory
